# Ruby on Rails - search in database based on a query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sql-like

I have a simple form, where I set up a query that I want to browse, for example **panasonic viera**.
This is on how I search the term in database:

```
Product.where("name ilike ?", "%#{params[:q]}%").order('price')
```

The query looks like **%panasonic viera%**, but I would need to search the query this way: **%panasonic%viera%** - I need to find all products, where is in the title the word **panasonic** or **viera**... but how to make this query?

Comment: WHERE name LIKE ? OR name LIKE ? (with multiple parameters)

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to search for the phrase "panasonic viera" (both words appearing in this order), or do you want to search for either "panasonic" or "vieara"?

Comment: "%#{params[:q].gsub(' ', '%')}%"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution would be to break up your query into individual terms and build a set of database queries connected by `OR`.

```
terms = params[:q].split
query = terms.map { |term| "name like '%#{term}%'" }.join(" OR ")
Product.where(query).order('price')
```

Comment: Thank you man for your answer. But to be honest, I am a bit confused, because: if I have this product: **KV VAIO E14A1S1EB** and if in the **params[:q]** is **sony vaio**, I would expect that this product should be found, but it doesn't. But how is is possible?

Comment: My guess is that it's something to do with case sensitivity - try upcasing your search string and see if that helps?

Comment: I have implemented the same, sorry to say its taking too much time to fetch result. My db has more than 100,000 records. Is there an efficient way?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using PostgreSQL, you can use [`pg_search`](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search) gem. It's support full text search, with option `any_word`:

```
Setting this attribute to true will perform a search which will return all models containing any word in the search terms.
```

Example from `pg_search`:

```
class Number < ActiveRecord::Base
  include PgSearch
  pg_search_scope :search_any_word,
                  :against => :text,
                  :using => {
                    :tsearch => {:any_word => true}
                  }

  pg_search_scope :search_all_words,
                  :against => :text
end

one = Number.create! :text => 'one'
two = Number.create! :text => 'two'
three = Number.create! :text => 'three'

Number.search_any_word('one two three') # => [one, two, three]
Number.search_all_words('one two three') # => []
```

Answer (score 1):

How about via [ARel](https://github.com/rails/arel)

```
def self.search(query)
  words      = query.split(/\s+/)
  table      = self.arel_table
  predicates = []

  words.each do |word|
    predicates << table[:name].matches("%#{word}%")
  end

  if predicates.size > 1
    first = predicates.shift
    conditions = Arel::Nodes::Grouping.new(predicates.inject(first) {|memo, expr| Arel::Nodes::Or.new(memo, expr)})
  else
    conditions = predicates.first
  end

  where(conditions).to_a
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't working?

```
 WHERE name LIKE "panasonic" OR name LIKE "viera"
```

Comment: The search query is coming from user input, so OP needs a solution that can dynamically build up a database query.