# How can I search a table based on multiple search criteria without require said criteria?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have created a table that houses product brochures.  I would like to allow the user to search the table based on three drop down menus (product type, carrier, concept).  I have created the menus and the controller currently passes through the params correctly.  If the user search by all 3 criteria, the search displays correctly.  If the user chooses only one or two search options however, the result is always nothing.  I understand why this is happening (the model is trying to search by all three criteria and when one is missing, it simply searches nil in that field), however I'm sure the correct solution.  Please help!  My model is below...thank you

```
def self.search (search_product_type, search_carrier, search_concept)

  if search_product_type.blank? && search_carrier.blank? && search_concept.blank?
    scoped
  else
    Ad.where(carrier_id: search_carrier)
      .where(product_type_id: search_product_type)
      .where(concept: search_concept)
  end
end
```

Comment: You should really consider looking into a gem to help you with what you describe. A **great** one for this is Ernie's **[Ransack](https://github.com/ernie/ransack)**. There's even a **[demo](http://ransack-demo.herokuapp.com/)** you can try out.

Comment: Thank you.. I'll attempt to implement this gem and post an update

Answer (score 1):

As @Deefour said in the comments you should use a gem. But, you can also make something like this:

```
def self.search (search_product_type, search_carrier, search_concept)

  if search_product_type.blank? && search_carrier.blank? && search_concept.blank?
    scoped
  else
    tmp = {}

    if search_carrier.present?
       tmp[:carrier_id] = search_carrier
    end

    if search_product_type.present?
       tmp[:product_type_id] = search_product_type
    end

    if search_carrier.present?
       tmp[:concept] = search_concept
    end

    Ad.where(tmp)
  end
end
```

Comment: It rarely gets much love, but I like doing this sort of thing in ARel if I'm going to do it by hand, as the flexibility is greater *(ie. you can mix and group OR and AND conditions **and** can pass the return value as an ARel expression if desired - for further processing later)*. An example of this is http://stackoverflow.com/a/13685504/605707

Comment: Cool, I haven't tried ARel in that way, I will make some tests... Thanks for the idea!

Comment: thanks @pablo89.  Unfortunately this did not have the desired result.  It only displays the correct results for the first search criteria.  The others display nothing