# Rails Search One Column On Multiple Saved Terms (Saved Searches In Model)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, search, rss

One table, one column ('headline' in an RSS feed reader). On the front end, I want a text area in which I can enter a comma-separated list of search terms, some multi-word, like for 'politics':

```
rajoy, pp, "popular party", "socialist party", etc
```

This could either be stored as part of a separate search model or as a keyword column on the 'category' or 'story' models, so they can be edited and improved with different terms from the front end, as a story develops.

In the RSS reader, have a series of links, one for each story or category, that, on being clicked return the headlines that contain one (or more) of the search terms from the stored list.

In a later version, it would be good to find headlines containing several of the terms in the list, but let's start simple.

Have been doing lots of reading about postgres, rails, different types of searches and queries, but can't seem to find what I want, which I understand is basically "search 'headlines' column against this list of search terms".

Sounds like it might be an array thing that's more to do with controllers in Rails than postgres, or cycling through a giant OR query with some multi-word terms, but I'm not sure.

Does anyone have any better pointers about how to start?

Answer (score 1):

### Users

If this will be user specific, I would start with a User model that is responsible for persisting each unique set of search terms.  Think logon or session.

Assuming you use the Category method mentioned before, and assuming there's a column called `name`.  Each search term would be stored as a separate instance in the database.  Think tags.

> headlines that contain one (or more) of the search terms from the stored list

### Categories

Since each Category has many terms, and all the queries are going to be OR queries, a model that joins the User and Category, storing a search term would be appropriate.

I'm also assuming you have a Story model that contains the actual stories, although this may not be persisted in the database.  I'm predicting your story model has a heading and a body.

### Terminal Console

`rails generage model SearchTerm query:string user:references category:references && rake db:migrate`

### Models

On your existing User and Category models you would add:

```
# app/models/user.rb
  has_many :search_terms
  has_many categories, through: :search_terms

# app/models/category.rb
  has_many :search_terms
  has_many :stories
```

### Rails Console

This will automatically make it possible for you to do this:

```
@user = User.last   # this is in the console, just to demonstrate
@category = Category.find_by_name("politics")
@user.search_terms.create {query: "rajoy", category: @category}
@user.search_terms.create {query: "pp", category: @category}
@user.search_terms.where(category_id: @category.id).pluck(:query)
-> ['rajoy', 'pp']
```

### Controllers

What you will want to do with your controller (probably the Category controller) is to parse your text field and update the search terms in the database.  If you want to require commas and spaces to separate fields, you could do:

```
@user.search_terms.where(category: @category).delete_all
params[:search_term][:query].split(", ").map{|x| x.gsub("\"", "")}.each do |term|
  @user.search_terms.create({category: @category, query: term})
end
```

### Front End

Personally though, I'd make the front end a bit less complicated to use, like either just require commas, no quotes, or just require spaces and quotes.

### Search

For the grand finale, for the Stories to be displayed that have search terms in their heading:

```
Story.where(@user.search_terms.where(category: @category).pluck(:query).map { |term| "heading like '%#{term}%'" }.join(" OR "))
```

I would recommend using pg_search gem rather than trying to maintain complicated queries like this.

Note: I'm sure there are errors in this, since I wasn't able to actually create the entire app to answer your questions.  I hope this helps you get started with what you actually need to do.  I encourage you as you work through this to post questions that have some code.

### References

- [Rails guides: choosing habtm or has many through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many)
- [gem 'pg_search'](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search)
- [Stack Overflow: Search a database based on query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685271/ruby-on-rails-search-in-database-based-on-a-query)

Comment: Hmmmm, an interesting start, Andy, thanks. Let me have a think on it first and I'll update later on this evening.